# Making call to Facebook's /me/feed connection but no post appears on my profile

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I just got the access token with `publish_stream`, but when i access below url in browsers, Its not posting message in my wall; It just displays all the feed contents.

Wwhat is the problem, I just want to post a simple message in wall by just visiting a URL like below; Am i wrong somewhere?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token={REMOVED}&message=hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things

1. That's a GET request, not a POST request - if you can't make a POST request via your code or SDK for some reason, you can simulate one by adding `&method=post` to the request
2. You included your access token in the question (now removed) - i strongly recommend changing your password on Facebook ASAP

Comment: I already removed some of the content in the middle of access token :D